# sudo useradd with PHP

Tags: php

I've just started checking out PHP and to sort of work it out I thought that I would make a form that adds a user to the system with PHP. I tried to run the command with `exec()`, but that yielded no results(I made sure that www-data is a sudoer), so I tried it with `system()` to get some output that might tell me what the problem was, but both of my outputs just returned a vague `1` and `6` in that order. Here is my code:

```
<?php $username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
?>

<html>
    <body>

        Welcome <?php echo $username; ?><br>
        Your password will be set to: <?php echo $password; ?>
        <?php system("sudo useradd -m $username", $output1);
        system("sudo usermod -g user $username", $output2);
        ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $output1;?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $output2;?>

    </body>
</html>
```

It correctly prints out the username and password variables, but seems to be unable to run the `sudo useradd` and `sudo usermod` commands, although I'm not entirely sure.Is there anything here that might give an Idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: sudo normally requires user interaction - you have to enter the sudo password at the prompt. That's likely to be the issue.

Comment: Would I use echo to enter the password? or just exec() or something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with `proc_open`?

Something like this...

```
        $cmd = "echo 1";
        $descriptorspec = array(
                0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
                1 => array('file', '/var/www/html/proc-output.txt', 'a'), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
                2 => array('file', '/var/www/html/error-output.txt', 'a') // stderr is a file to write to
        );
        $pipes = [];
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        $return_value = is_resource($process) ? proc_close($process) : die('this does not work');
```

How you input the www-data password?

Comment: Aha. I didn't think of the sudoing password requirement. As far as I know, It doesn't have one yet so I'll set one and see how that goes with some code to input it.